# WPF Resource Path Error

Tags: wpf, file, xaml, resources, filepath

**Please read the Edit on the Bottom!**

I am building a desktop program using wpf and I am trying to access a resource in the xaml. 
I have a folder in my solution were I added a .stl file, so I can display it in 3D using the Helix Toolkit. 
So I added the tag:

```
<h:FileModelVisual3D x:Name="model1" Source="Resources/Model.stl"/>
```

For what I had read on the Internet, I expected this to reference the Resource file under the project, which has the file. But Visual Studio 2013 says:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Resources\Model.stl'.

And if I change it to:

```
<h:FileModelVisual3D x:Name="model1" Source="/Resources/Model.stl"/>
```

The error is:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Resources\Model.stl'.

So in both cases the path is being expanded in the wrong way.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

The errors were coming from Visual Studio intellisense, when I built the project, it says it can not be found on the debug folder...... Shouldn't Visual Studio been generating the Resources folder in the bin's Debug folder? Or do I have to specify it to auto generate it? How do I proceed?

Comment: Try Source="./Resources/Model.stl" also make sure that the object is included in your project and has a "Build Action" is Resource.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by acessing the file's build actions under the properties tab and change it to `Copy if newer`.

Answer (score 1):

If the resource is not in the same project :

```
Source=pack://application:,,,/[AssemblyName];component/Resources/Model.stl"
```

Also go to the properties of the Model.stl in VS and set :

1. Build action : **Resource**.
   *Or similar:*
2. Build action : **Content**; 
   Copy to output directory : **Copy if newer**